# Understanding of C++ application load balancing

Tags: c++, performance, scalability, load-balancing

Say, i have 1 CPU-intensive C++ console application(game server). Do i need to program it specially to have ability to scale 1 application on several machines or there is special software to make 2-3 servers act as single?

UPDATE: I have login server seperated from game server. Server has a place where all players meet together but there is no such cpu work. The most in game threads, player create a game - 1 thread.

As i understood i need to program application to be able to create game instance on another server machine?

Comment: If you don't program it to work from different instances, you may have funny things such as users being able to login simultaneously on different instances of the application.

Comment: Yeah i didnt program it to work with different server instances on different machines. First i'd like to find solution without recoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to program the server in such a way that it knows there may be other instances of itself - for example by getting just part of the tasks as its responsibility in such a way that other instances will know someone else is doing that and not take it twice.

For the load balancing - there are some software that does automatic load balancing but load balancing can only work correctly if the actual server support that.

Comment: So, there are no possibility to just start software, connect 3 server blades to each other and run single application that will think that it is a single server?

Comment: It really depends on the server. If it is just input-processing-output then it might work. But if it executes some more sophisticated logic, keeping state, caching, etc. then there is a big chance the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to program it with load balancing in mind.

If you have it running already, try to make as much stuff threadable as possible to enable it to use extra cores/extra cpus on multi-cpu/multi-core machines.

Then look at moving meta-game information to a separate machine to handle login information, etc.